# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while trying to sum up binary numbers

Tags: java, exception, vector, binary

// I am new to this, I am trying to add here two binary numbers, but I get this exception, I know that it may be more than a thing or two to change here for this to work but I really want to know what I am doing wrong here, thanks !

```
import java.util.*;
public class Problema2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size;
    int tineminte=0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Marimea celor doua numere ce urmeaza sa fie adunate:");
    size=input.nextInt();

    int counter=0;  
    Vector<Integer> A = new Vector<Integer>();
    System.out.println("Primul numar in forma binara:");
    while(counter<size)
    {
        A.add(counter,input.nextInt());
        counter++;
    }
    System.out.println("Primul numar in forma binara este:");
    for(counter=0;counter<size;counter++)
        System.out.println(A.elementAt(counter));


    counter=0;  





    Vector<Integer> B = new Vector<Integer>();
    System.out.println("Al doilea numar in forma binara:");
    while(counter<size)
    {
        B.add(counter,input.nextInt());
        counter++;

    }


    System.out.println("Al doilea numar in forma binara este:");
    for(counter=0;counter<size;counter++)
        System.out.println(B.elementAt(counter));



    Vector<Integer> C = new Vector<Integer>();

    counter=size-1;

    while(counter!=-1)
    {
        if(A.elementAt(counter)==1&&B.elementAt(counter)==0) 
        {   if(tineminte==1)

            C.insertElementAt(0, counter);

        else
            C.insertElementAt(1, counter);

        counter--;
        }
        else
            if(A.elementAt(counter)==0&&B.elementAt(counter)==1) 
            { if(tineminte==1){
                C.insertElementAt(0, counter);
            }
            else
                C.insertElementAt(1, counter);

            counter--;
            }
            else
                if(A.elementAt(counter)==0&&B.elementAt(counter)==0)

                {  if(tineminte==1){
                    tineminte=0;
                    C.insertElementAt(1, counter);
                }
                else 
                    C.insertElementAt(0, counter);

                counter--;
                }
                else
                    if(A.elementAt(counter)==1&&B.elementAt(counter)==1) 
                    { 

                        if(tineminte==1){C.insertElementAt(1, counter);

                        }
                        else

                            C.insertElementAt(0, counter);


                        tineminte=1;

                        counter--;
                    }

    }
    System.out.println("Suma:");        
    for(int i:C)
        System.out.println(C.elementAt(i)); 

}
}
```

Comment: you're not going to tell us the line that caused the exception?

Comment: Well, I don't have any idea which one is that, all I know it is somewhere around that part of the code which configures the binary summing of two binary numbers. I am new to this site so yes , I probably need to be more specific next time, I am sorry if this is confusing. On second thought, the exception appears after I type the second binary number to sum up .

Comment: The line# is included in the error message that you posted part of.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 > 0
 at java.util.Vector.insertElementAt(Unknown Source)
 at Problema2.main(Problema2.java:103)  This is what I get when I try to sum up 2 binary numbers which have 3 length each.

Comment: `Problema2.java:103` - that's the file, and line # of the exception. Using that information, it should be simple for you to tell us the line that your error occurs on.

Comment: the 103th line is  C.insertElementAt(0, counter); - the one below the if(A.elementAt(counter)==1&&B.elementAt(counter)==1) ...not the next below, there are some codelines before reaching the one that generates the exception

Comment: There you have it -- `counter` is 2 when the current vector size is zero.

Comment: Perfect! So then, it's telling you that your array access there is out of bounds, you are trying to access element 2, when your size is only 0 (`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 > 0`). Since you start with `counter=size-1;` and `C` empty, you get an exception trying to insert an element into the 2nd slot of an empty vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size;
        int tineminte = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out
                .println("Input number of bits:");
        size = input.nextInt();

        int counter = 0;
        Vector<Integer> A = new Vector<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Input First number in binary");
        while (counter < size) {
            A.add(counter, input.nextInt());
            counter++;
        }
        System.out.println("First number in binary (output):");
        for (counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
            System.out.println(A.elementAt(counter));

        counter = 0;

        Vector<Integer> B = new Vector<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Input second number in binary:");
        while (counter < size) {
            B.add(counter, input.nextInt());
            counter++;

        }

        System.out.println("Second number in binary (output):");
        for (counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
            System.out.println(B.elementAt(counter));

        Vector<Integer> C = new Vector<Integer>();

        counter = size - 1;

        while (counter != -1) {
            if (A.elementAt(counter) == 1 && B.elementAt(counter) == 0) {
                if (tineminte == 1)
                    C.add(0);

                else
                    C.add(1);

                counter--;
            } else if (A.elementAt(counter) == 0 && B.elementAt(counter) == 1) {
                if (tineminte == 1) {
                    C.add(0);
                } else
                    C.add(1);

                counter--;
            } else if (A.elementAt(counter) == 0 && B.elementAt(counter) == 0)

            {
                if (tineminte == 1) {
                    tineminte = 0;
                    C.add(1);
                } else
                    C.add(0);

                counter--;
            } else if (A.elementAt(counter) == 1 && B.elementAt(counter) == 1) {

                if (tineminte == 1) {
                    C.add(1);

                } else

                    C.add(0);

                tineminte = 1;

                counter--;
            }

        }
        // You forgot the last bit
             if (tineminte==1)
            C.add(1);
        System.out.println("Suma:");
        for(int i=C.size()-1;i>=0;i--) {
            System.out.println(C.elementAt(i));
        }

    }
```

**Note:** I've tried to change only the necessary parts of your code.

Comment: ok but by using the add method I can't specific where to insert the element at.

Comment: @user3412387 You are inserting the numbers sequentially.

Comment: A Vector *is* a form of array.

Comment: @HotLicks But if you have not space, you can't insert. An option could be making a for loop of `add(0)` at the beggining.

Comment: @rpax wow this changes you've made to my code are really cool, thank you ! I can't believe I didn't use this site ever before, thanks !

Comment: Of course, one could simply do `setSize` on the Vector, to make it the appropriate size.

Comment: @HotLicks you're right. I forgot that one. +1 at your comment :)